# Custom toolbox imported without elements

Tags: customization, enterprise-architect

I created a profile in order to create a custom toolbox.

I export the profile as XML file, and import it to a new project:
 The new toolbox is added as expected, but without any elements in it.

Resources panel: the profile has no hierarchy.

[image]

The Profile diagram:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToolboxPage «metaclass» should be the target of extensions from one or more «stereotype» classes, each of which represents one "page" (= expandable section) of the toolbox. Within each such class, the elements and/or connectors should be represented as attributes.

In your example, it looks like you're drawing extensions not from proper toolbox page classes but from the elements you want in the toolbox. This won't work.

If you're unclear about the proper representation, use the profile helpers.

**EDIT**: The "Profile Helpers" [webinar video](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/webinar/webinar-20130130-extending-ea.html) on the following page is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I set the extension relation from stereotypes to the metaclass. When I try to drag the relation from the metaclass to the elements, I get relations in the same direction. Any ideas?